# Unsure why Javascript eventListener is not linking up to SVG element?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, event-listener

Hi I am working on a problem here, I have put together a simple SVG circle, and I am looking to connect some JS code to it in order to change the colour from blue to red on the first click, and then back to blue on the second click.

The code is posted below, and I have put it through a syntax checker with everything apparently being in order.

So maybe the logic I am using is way off, or its something minor. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, thanks

```html
`<svg id="circles" width="66%" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 700 666">

  <circle id="shape" class="svgCircle" cx="170" cy="125" r="20" fill="#1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />

<script>

var shapeClick = document.getElementById("shape").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
var clicks = 0;

function changeColor(){

  if (shape.fill == "rgb(29, 172, 249)")
  {
    shape.fill == "rgb(255, 0, 0)";

  }
  else {

    shape.fill == "rgb(29, 172, 249)";
  }


}


</script>

</svg>






`
```

Comment: what is `seat0` ?

Comment: just corrected it, been looking at this for too long!

Comment: Your eventListener is fine, but shape.fill is 'undefined'. You could access it via 'shape.setAttribute()' like here - https://jsfiddle.net/1ejtLL62/2

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to work on your jsfiddle, but when I place it in my .js file it won't even turn red. Do you think it would make a difference if I swapped the rgb number for the #1dacf9?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var shapeClick = document.getElementById("shape").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
var clicks = 0;

function changeColor(){
  if (shape.style.fill == "rgb(29, 172, 249)")
  {
    shape.style.fill = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";

  }
  else {

    shape.style.fill = "rgb(29, 172, 249)";
  }


}
```

```html
<svg id="circles" width="66%" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 700 666">

  <circle id="shape" class="seat" cx="170" cy="125" r="20" style="fill: #1dacf9" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />

</svg>
```